# How to mavenize Grails 2 Application with build-test-data plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to mavenize my grails 2.1 app which uses build-test-data-2.0.3, for some reason it cannot import grails.test.mixin.support.*.

I thought it has something to do with the scopes so I tried different of them but it did not help.

My assumption is grails.test.mixin.support and other requirements are already downloaded with grails core, do I need to add any specific dependency for this plugin ?

Thanks

The error I am getting is:

```
 package grails.test.mixin.support does not exist
```

Here is what needs to be done to create the issue:

1- create-app delme

2- adding build-test-plugin

3- create-pom com.company

4- mvn install

This is my dependency in pom:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-test-data</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

BuildConfig:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

    compile ':cache:1.0.0'
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does your BuildConfig.groovy look like ? I have the same setup and I don't see the issue.

Comment: I have not changed the Buidlconfig, since I am using maven to download the dependencies.

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts Are you using maven too?

Comment: Yes I'm also using maven. I don't see the error

Comment: You'll need to add `pom true` to your `grails.project.dependency.resolution` closure if you want Grails to pick up dependencies from your pom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone encountered similar issue that maven cannot compile some of the classes this might be helpful to them.

In my case it was some classes used by build-test-data plugin that maven was complaining about. The problem is Maven was not aware of those classes that build-test-data was using in this case it was grails.test.mixin.support.MixinMethod. This is part of the grails-plugin-testing package.

Maven needs to know that so it can put it in the classpath (I assume) and if it cannot find it, will fail to compile it. What I needed to do was just adding that dependency to maven, so maven can put that in the classpath.

Thanks to [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/mavenized-grails-project-td3571270.html) respond by jpearlin helped me to resolve this issue.

I added this dependency and the issue was fixed.

```
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
              <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
              <version>${grails.version}</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```